Error in Xamarin Forms iOS when generating the distribution The assembly System.Diagnostics.Process.dll was loaded from a different path than provided
The error occurs only in the iOS project, and only when I generate the distribution version. There is no error during local distribution (internal developer distribution). Other errors occurred before this one related to the DLL, but I managed to resolve them. However, I haven't been able to resolve this one.
Attached are the images:
This is the distribution certificate
The error occurs as soon as I generate the file
DLLs of the iOS project
Project DLLs
I have tried various solutions, such as updating all packages and adding the DLL that causes the error, but none have been successful.
Log from the build:
Image:
3
4
5
6

Have you tried just running msbuild? Perhaps it is a Visual Studio for Mac issue? What does the build output look like, can you provide the log from the build?
